How to add typing to Firebase Functions handlers V2?
I have the following function
export async function onDeleteVideo(event: FirestoreEvent<QueryDocumentSnapshot, { uid: string }>): Promise<any> {
  if (!event) {
    return
  }

  const { disposables } = event.data.data()

  for (const disposable of disposables) {
    try {
      await storage.bucket(disposable.bucket).file(disposable.object).delete()
    } catch {}
  }
}

Exported as
export const onDeleteVideo = onDocumentDeleted('videos/{uid}', triggers.onDeleteVideo)

However, event.data.data() or disposables are any. How to add my type, which is an interface named Video?

Please edit the question to show the complete code sample that doesn't compile, including your imports.  We should be able to copy your code and paste it into a new project to reproduce the problem.  Also consider that maybe your TypeScript configuration is important here.

I wanted to ask the same of Google because the documentation is always incomplete, and I have to keep hunting for the imports.

Why don't you edit the question to show us what you ended up trying, so we can see what you might be doing wrong?  It will be helpful for others in the future in the same situation.  Also, if you have a problem with the documentation, use the "send feedback" button at the top of any page.

Wouldn't this work?
export async function onDeleteVideo(event: FirestoreEvent<QueryDocumentSnapshot, Video>): Promise<any> {
  if (!event) {
    return
  }

  const { disposables } = event.data.data()

  for (const disposable of disposables) {
    try {
      await storage.bucket(disposable.bucket).file(disposable.object).delete()
    } catch {}
  }
}

and the Video interface would be something like:
interface Video {
  uid: string;
  disposables: Array<{
    bucket: string;
    object: string;
  }>;
}


If I use Video, I get this error
https://pastebin.com/nk2C4ENy

From where do you import FirestoreEvent?

I simple give up, f*** Google. They do not proper document the API that THEY want us to use!

They are not doing a favor, they must to make a cristal clear documentation with clear examples.
